# Java JPA EclipseLink ManyToMany INSERT

Tags: java, jpa, nullpointerexception, eclipselink

I have the following ManyToMany association within my Project:

Class User:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="antrag_id")}
)
private List<Antrag> antraege;
```

And Class Antrag:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="antraege",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<User> users;
```

I am trying to correctly insert a new record, this - I think works not correctly. When I'm trying to "reselect" all Antraege of User, I am getting a `NullPointerException` on `antraege.getUsers()`. Only when I restart the java swing application, `antraege.getUsers()` doesn't return null.

Code for Inserting my new ManyToMany record:

```
Antrag antrag = new Antrag();
antrag.setBetreff(betreff);
antragBusiness.create(antrag);

betreuer.getAntraege().add(antrag);
currentUser.getAntraege().add(antrag);

userBusiness.update(betreuer);
userBusiness.update(currentUser);
```

Where my create method uses persist and the update method uses merge.

As I've said, they get inserted correctly into the database, but when I try to call:

```
List<Antrag> antraege = (List<Antrag>) user.getAntraege();

for(Antrag a : antraege){

    News n = new News();
    n.setDatum(a.getCreatedAt());
    n.setStatus(a.isStatus());
    n.setThema(a.getInfo());

    List<User> beteiligte = a.getUsers();       

    System.out.println("Amount users " + beteiligte.size());
    for (User z : beteiligte) {
        System.out.println(z.getNachname() + " " + z.getId());
        if(z.getId() != user.getId()){
            n.setZustaendiger(z);
        }
    }

    newsList.add(n);
}
```

-> Amount users returns 0 :(

So - in consequences: Antraege are added to Users, but users not to Antraege?

Edit: As it seems, my insertion of a new ManyToMany record is not correct.
Can anyone explain me the correct way ?

Comment: Do you add users to antraeges in your code? If not, that's why users are not added to antraeges. It's **your** responsibility to maintain the coherence of the association.

Comment: Hi JB, its the first time i am using the ManyToMany in this project. Could you please explain me on how to correctly add / insert the new ManyToMany record/s ? Regards and thank you.

Comment: You set your user's list of antraege objects, but not the antrag's list of users.  If you don't add the user to the antrag's list, it will only ever be empty unless you force a refresh using em.refresh(), restart the app or otherwise clear the cache so it gets reloaded from the database.  It is much cheaper to just maintain both sides of bidirectional relationships upfront - JPA does not set your relationships for you.